# Ошибка: null value in column "bld_code" violates not-null constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

```
SELECT CONCAT (COALESCE(id_street), COALESCE(bld_no)) FROM iota_cmac
```

выдаёт нормальный результат

```
'9031546460179 025'
```

При попытке вставить это значение в пустое поле id_bld этой же таблицы:

```
INSERT INTO iota_cmac.bld_54646(id_bld)
SELECT CONCAT (COALESCE(id_street), COALESCE(bld_no)) 
FROM iota_cmac.bld_54646;
```

выдаёт ошибку:

```
ERROR: null value in column "bld_code" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (9031546460179 025 , null, null, null, null,   null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).
SQL state: 23502
```

Вопрос: причём тут остальные поля таблицы, если CONCAT выбирает только два указанных поля?
Указание на значение CONCAT ничего не меняет, ошибка точно такая же.

```
INSERT INTO iota_cmac.bld_54646(id_bld) 
SELECT CONCAT (COALESCE(id_street), COALESCE(bld_no)) 
FROM iota_cmac.bld_54646 
VALUES (CONCAT);
```

как я понимаю этот стейтмент, команда INSERT должна вставить в поле id_bld результат CONCAT: '9031546460179 025' и прекратить исполнение, а она продолжает проверять остальные поля. При этом, все поля ЗАПОЛНЕНЫ, а не пустые, как пишет в ошибке.

Если кто может разъяснить, буду признателен

Comment: Когда вы пишете `insert` вы создаете новую строку в таблице. И в этой строке заполнено только 1 поле, `id_bld`. У вас на таблице есть ограничение, которого говорит что поле `bld_code` не может быть пустым. Возможно вы хотели сделать `update` ?

Comment: Спасибо, я понял ошибку, правильно так:
    UPDATE iota_cmac.bld_54646 
    SET (id_bld) = 
    (SELECT CONCAT (COALESCE(id_street), COALESCE(bld_no)) 
    FROM iota_cmac.bld_54646);

Comment: @Viktorov Не знаю как поставить здесь Вам плюс к карме ))) ... спасибо за подсказку